# Getting a key error on the object I'm sending to the server (jQuery -> Python)

Tags: jquery, python, post, request, pyramid

Below is the login object I'm sending to the server:

```
Object {username: "hi@hi.com", password: "password"}
```

It contains an invalid username and password.

Here in the python it checks the POST, and then checks the username

```
try:
        print self.request.POST
        username = str(self.request.POST['username'])
```

The Print returns the following:

```
MultiDict([('{"username":"hi@hi.com","password":"password"}', '******')])
```

However it errors out on the `username = line`

The exception block:

```
except Exception, ex:
        print ex.message
```

The exception is `ex = {KeyError}'username'`

Any thoughts as to why `username = str(self.request.POST['username'])` is not fetching the username from the POST?

---

The HTML form (action removed because I can't show error messages otherwise)

```
<!-- LOGIN -->
<div id="login-form">
    <form class="login-form" action="" method="post">

    <input type="text"
        id="login-email" value="email" name="username"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'email';}"
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'email') {this.value = '';}"
        autocomplete="off"/>

    <div class="tip-error-message" id="error-email"><span>A valid email is required</span></div>

    <input type="password"
        id="login-password" value="password" name="password"
        onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}"
        onfocus="if (this.value == 'password') {this.value = '';}"
        autocomplete="off"/>

        <button id="login_page_submit" type="submit">login</button>

    <div id="login-form-background"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in the jQuery I have this, so when I get an error response back I can display the message on the page:

```
$('#login-form').unbind('submit').bind("submit", function(event) {

 WHOAT.validation.validateLoginForm('#login-form'); // custom validation

     var params = {
        username : '',
        password : ''
     }

    params.username = $('#login-email').val();
    params.password = $('#login-password').val();

    console.log(params.username); // hi@hi.com 
    console.log(params.password); // password

    WHOAT.networking.postToServerWithAjax('/login', params, function (response) {

        console.log(response);

    });

       return false;

});
```

the **postToServerWithAjax** function

```
var postToServerWithAjax = function (url, params, callback) {
    console.log('postToServerWithAjax:');
    console.log(url);    //returns: login 
    console.log(params); //returns: Object {username: "hi@hi.com", password: "password"} 
    invokeServer(url, params, callback, 'POST');
}
```

the **invokeServer** function

```
var invokeServer = function(url, params, callback, postMethod) {
    WHOAT.analytics.trackPageView(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: postMethod,
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        //contentType: 'charset=utf-8',
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            },
            201: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            },
            400: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can access `self.request.POST['{"username":"hi@hi.com","password":"password"}']` (and it'll return `'******'`); this is obviously not what you wanted. How did you POST the object to the server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I added the form HTML and the jQuery block I'm using

Comment: You are turning your parameters to JSON **always**? That won't work, unless your server explicitly parses the JSON again. What framework do you use for the server? Django or Flask or something else?

Comment: Using the Pyramid framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting JSON-encoded data, not form-encoded or URL-encoded data.

Access the JSON-encoded object with the [`requests.json_body`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/webob.html#request-json-body) attribute:

```
username = self.request.json_body['username']
```

Comment: The backend guy finally came over and wrote this `data = self.request.body
            data = urllib2.unquote(data)
            data = data[:-1]
            obj = tools.unjson(data)`

Comment: So yeah thanks, my problem was with the JSON, it wasn't understanding it